# How to differentiate between 0 and blank in excel

Tags: excel

Is there a way that I can get a FALSE from an if statement testing if one cell is equal to the other

Example table for the test:

[image]

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Use `ISBLANK()` function ;)

Comment: Just an FYI: If you copy/paste your post title into Google, the first result has the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use EXACT, which will compare the string text and not the numbers:

```
=IF(EXACT(A2,B2),"Match","No Match")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, excel has an ISBLANK function that returns TRUE if a cell is blank. In your case, you could write your formula like this:

```
=IF(AND(A2=B2, NOT(ISBLANK(B2))), "Match", "No match")
```